# Harmony destructuring ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-harmony

This a weird behaviour, i've tested on Chrome and works just fine without any flag, but in node it doesn't work event with the latest version

```
$ node --harmony_destructuring app.js

[length, offset] = this.getint(data, offset, 2)
^    
ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

$ node -v

v5.11.0
```

Any clues on why it doesn't work or a version of node in witch works?

Thanks

Comment: should be `var [length, offset] = this.getint(data, offset, 2)`

Comment: you can't have implicit globals in modules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax would be

```
const iterable = ['a', 'b'];
const [x, y] = iterable;
```

You can read more on destructuring [here](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_destructuring.html).